# How to add html horizontal line to option of select tag in html

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I want to display a html horizontal line in the html select option tag as shown in the below image.
[image]
The color of the line should be different for each option tag. 
I tried with the below code which didn't work for me:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="AddAndEdit">
      <div>
      </div id="div1">
      <div>
       <select name="list" id="personlist">
          <option value="11">Person1<hr width="30" style='color:red'></option>
          <option value="27">Person2<hr width="30" style='color:red'></option>
          <option value="17">Person3<hr width="30" style='color:green'></option>     
       </select>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="submit""/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot style the option in that way. Moreover, you cannot control the appearance of the select completely across all browsers, OS. I suggest to use some plugins such as select2,selectize

Comment: please make a fiddle of your code so that others can easily see and edit your code to help you out

Answer (score 0):

If you possible to use select2 library. Go through below link and follow the under templating section example. 
http://select2.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 0):

Default select drop-down will not give you any help for this but you can user twitter bootstrap dopdowns for this purpose

Here check this w3link
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

It suggests

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class='divider'></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```